# Why do I get "ReferenceError: test is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Within my Google Script Project I got two GS files `Code.gs` and `other.gs`.

code.gs looks like

```
var globalSettings = {};
settings();


function settings(){
  other();
  globalSettings.fileName = "file";
  console.log("settings was executed");
}

function primary(){

  console.log("primary was executed");
}
```

other.gs looks like

```
function other(){

  console.log("other was executed");
}
```

when I run the function `primary` I get

```
ReferenceError: other is not defined
settings    @ Code.gs:5
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:1
```

when I move the function `other` to the file `code` it works. Could someone explain why? Is there any way the other file could be anywhere in the project?

Comment: Why would you wish to place a function call in global scope? I can only imagine doing it if I was asking a question that I already knew the answer to.

Comment: I am not a professional coder...  I place the function in global scope because it set settings that I need all through the whole project. I though I was a good idea how how how to have the settings ready every time. If there is any other proper way I will change it.

Comment: Making variable declarations inside of settings will not produce global variables. I would use the const declaration in global scope or the PropertiesService.  The great thing about PropertiesService is that they can change from function to function and global variables can't.

Comment: I updated the question so it looks exactly as I use it. I declare the variable outside the function settings();

Comment: The problem with `var globalSettings = {};` is that everytime you make a function call `globalSettings` is set equal to an empty object.  So you can not use it to store state between function calls

Comment: why would the variable `globalSettings` be set to an empty object? And even if it was sothen I set everything inside function `settings()`.

Comment: I am listening how to do it differently if it is better. I was thinking of using `PropertiesService` but did not go this way. The question is why the place where the function is matters. I thought I can place it anywhere in a project.

Comment: This maybe actually something to consider.  After chatting with you I played around with idea and I find it to be an interesting approach: `const gobj={get init(){delete this.init;this.init=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();}};
 readInit();

function readInit() {
  gobj.init;
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(gobj.init))
}`  Here's a reference from a question TheMaster asked and answered One of the neat things about this is that it's real easy to access PropertiesService and it could be used to maintain state although it doesn't update except between function calls

Comment: it is quite too complex for me. What does it do?

Comment: It creates an instance of the properties service object between function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

**Everytime** you call a function (in any script in your project), the global variables are **automatically executed**.

- This is why if you define `var globalSettings = {}` as a global decleration, every time you run any function in the project, all the global calls will be executed and therefore `globalSettings` will be set to an empty object and this is why I don't use global variables.
- The *global call* `other` and the *function decleration* `other` need to be in the same `gs` script in order to work. Or you could simply call `other` from within the functions `settings` or `primary` and in this way `other` can stay in a separate script.

For example this would work perfectly fine:

**`code.gs`**

```
// define global variables
var globalSettings = {};

// adjust global variables here as a helper function
function settings(){
  other();
  globalSettings.fileName = "file";
  console.log("settings was executed");
}

// main function to be executed
function primary(){
  settings(); // call settings
  console.log(globalSettings.fileName);
  console.log(globalSettings.date);
  console.log("primary was executed");
}
```

**`other.gs`**

```
// make additional adjustments to the global variables
function other(){
  globalSettings.date = "today";
  console.log("other was executed");
}
```

**Suggestion:**

A better idea to make sure you don't execute your global declerations, is to use the Class [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) class to store some script or user data and then you can retrieve them either globally or locally (inside the functions) and this will make sure you won't execute them accidentally upon every execution as it is the case for the global declerations.

Comment: hm, I can see that using global variable will not be efficient. But I have 10 .gs files in my project.

Comment: can I somehow call a function when setting up `scriptProperties.setProperty` ?

Comment: @Radek yes, you can either call that function from another function (not as a global decleration), or put that function inside the same `.gs` where you have defined the global call. Namely, put the function decleration of `other` in the `code.gs` **or** put the call `other` inside `primary` and run primary. You can't run as a global decleration a function that is defined in another `gs` file. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: does it mean that whatever function I call inside `settings();` and whatever function that is called from any function that is inside `settings();` must be in the same `.gs` file?

Comment: @Radek No, please see my answer. You can call `other` from `settings` or `primary` but **not** as a global call. In your question, you call `settings` which calls `other` as a global call. Because `settings()` is executed as a global call.

Comment: @Radek you can put all your global variables outside of any function, then use `settings` to adjust the variables (assign properties etc). Your only job would be to run the `primary` function that will execute `settings` and the rest of the code.

Comment: I did not get what a global call means. I think I understood now. But I do not call `settings()` as a global call then `globalSettings.fileName ` will not be set when needed. I use this project as a libraty. So when I call  `other()` I need to have all settings set. The settings is NOT just a static text. It is set dynamically.

Comment: @Radek see my updated answer. You can also use `other` from `settings` to adjust the global variables. If you need to make it more dynamic, you can have parameters in your function. E.g. `other(data1,data2)` and pass data from `settings` or even from `primary` if `settings` has also parameters. Your code will execute `primary` and upon execution it will adjust the settings as they are chosen in `settings` and `other`.

Comment: So the solution for me is `not to call` settings() as a global call but to call in in every function I need to get the global settings. This will make the whole project more efficient too. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Radek yes! exactly!! so define your global variables e.g. `globalSettings` outside of any function and then you can use some functions to adjust these settings e.g. `settings` or `others` and call these functions from the `primary` one and you can always use `globalSettings` since it is globally defined.

Comment: any chance you can help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916488/how-to-migrate-google-application-script-project-to-different-a-account

Comment: @Radek unfortunately I am not familiar with this but I will have a look.